# prevent ajax element to be loaded without a parent

Tags: php, ajax

How do you prevent a page that is normally loaded through ajax to be loaded on its own? If for example in main.php you load via ajax "cart.php" and parse it to a local div. Would it be possible when an user attempts to directly load cart.php, the user is redirected to  main.php  instead?

--comment: javascript is not an option

Comment: Using .htaccess or php it is possible. Look up htaccess redirect, and PHP `$_SERVER` for ajax calls and `header location`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect if the page is loaded via ajax like this:

```
    if(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
      /* special ajax here */
      header("Location: http://www.example.com/main.php");
    }
```

Comment: Note `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` is only sent with certain major ajax frameworks, such as jQuery, etc. It is not 100% reliable.

Comment: @Steven yeah i noticed this as well. I haven't converted this script into jQuery yet so HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH isn't working. I'll take a look at your solution through htaccess or just send a variable through ajax and then check it in the php script and redirect if it isn't there...

Comment: Another reason to use jquery.